# Codecademy: Javascript - Code Your Own Adventure/Adding Some Story ERROR! :(

Tags: javascript

> Oops, try again. **Make sure your string is correct and is between quotation marks!**

This is the error that I keep receiving on Part 3: "Adding Some Story" of the second course on Javascript via Codecademy.com--*"Code Your Own Adventure"*.

Here is what I have prior to adding a single line for this section--

```
confirm("I am ready to get silly!");
var age = prompt("What's your age");
if( age < 13)
{
    console.log=("You are allowed to play, but I take no responsibility.");
}
else
{
    console.log=("GO GET CRAZY!");
}
```

Then, the instructions are written as--

**Under all your previous code, print out the following introduction, exactly as it is written.**

***"You are at a Justin Bieber concert, and you hear this lyric 'Lace my shoes off, start racing.'"***

**Print the introduction using console.log. Remember that the introduction is a string, so make sure to keep it between quotes.**

So then I add in:

```
console.log=("You are at a Justin Bieber concert, and you hear this lyric 'Lace my shoes off, start racing.'");
```

And I continue to get the same error I mentioned above:

> Oops, try again. **Make sure your string is correct and is between quotation marks!**

This continues to happen no matter what sorts of variations of the "introduction" I try to input. Please help!

[Here is a link to the course page of this lesson.](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-x9DnD/0/3?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `=` in `console.log=("...");`. [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) is a method that you can invoke by passing data (in your case, a string) as parameters within the parentheses. `=` is the assignment operator and it's not used when invoking functions/methods.

Comment: in **all** the `console.log=...`

Comment: Yeah. In fact I noticed OP put equal sign for console.log function

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` is a function. It essentially is the function `log` in the class `console`. So if for example you made a class `food` and a function `cook` in that class, you'd call it like: `food.cook()`

With that explained, `console.log("...")` is the format you want. Exactly how you used `prompt("What's your age")` just without a return variable.